# Get selected options from from ajax-chosen plugin

Tags: jquery, html-select, jquery-chosen

I am trying to figure out how to get selected options from [ajax-Chosen](https://github.com/meltingice/ajax-chosen) plugin with no luck.

This is my html:

```
<select multiple='multiple' class='chzn-select' data-placeholder='users'>
  <option value='0' selected>username1</option>
  <option value='1' selected>username2</option>
</select>
```

And this is JS part:

```
$(".chzn-select").ajaxChosen({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'users.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  minTermLength: 3,
  afterTypeDelay: 300
}, function (data) {
  var terms = {};

  $.each(data, function (i, val) {
     terms[i] = val;
  });

  return terms;
});
```

This all works fine. But when I remove one option "username2" the select field does not get updated. So when I want to get all selected users from list I get wrong list - in this case I always get both values even that one was removed from list.

I've also tried to trigger update with no luck:

```
$(".chzn-select").trigger("liszt:updated");
```

Does anyone have a suggestion how to get real values from select list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found a solution thanks to [stof](https://github.com/stof):

Instead of `$(".chosen-select option").each();`
I did this: `$(".chosen-select).val();`